# Upper semicontinuity of a function.

Tags: solution-verification, semicontinuous-functions

> > Suppose $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. A function $f: E\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be upper semicontinuous at $x_0 \in E$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $x\in E$, $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon$. If $f$ is upper semicontinuous at every point of $E$, then $f$ is upper semicontinuous on $E$.

Let $u: \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be a function defined by
\begin{align*}
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, \quad x\leq 0,\\
\frac{x}{2},\quad 0<x<1,\\
1,\quad x\geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I want to show that $u$ is upper semicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
Since continuous function is both upper semicontinuous and lower semicontinuous, so I think, I just need to show that $u$ is upper semicontinuous at its discontinuity points, i.e $0$ and $1$.

For $x=0$ (then $u(x)=\frac{1}{2}$). Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$. Take any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|y-0|=|y|<\frac{1}{2}$ . Therefore $-\frac{1}{2}<y<\frac{1}{2}$. Then, for $-\frac{1}{2}<y<0$, we have $u(y)=\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon.$
For $0<y<\frac{1}{2}$, we have $u(y)<\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon.$
So, $u$ is upper semicontinuous at $x=0$.

For $x=1$ (then $u(x)=1$). Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$. Take any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|y-1|<\frac{1}{2}$ . Therefore $\frac{1}{2}<y<\frac{3}{2}$. Then, for $\frac{1}{2}<y<1$, we have $u(y)<\frac{1}{2}<1+\varepsilon.$
For $1\leq y<\frac{3}{2}$, we have $u(y)=1<1+\varepsilon.$
So, $u$ is upper semicontinuous at $x=1$.

Is it correct?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks fine. Might be simpler to note that $u(x) \le u(0) = {1 \over 2}$ for $|x| < { 1\over 2}$, and $u(x) \le u(1) =1 $ for $|x-1| < { 1 \over 2}$. Hence for any $\epsilon>0$ choosing $\delta={1 \over 2}$ yields the desired result.

Comment: @copper.hat How can it be simpler if it's exactly the same proof, just stripped of its formal structure?

Comment: @Adayah brevity is the soul of wit.